# like clause in spring jdbc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

```
@Override
public List<String> getusers(String role) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String namecount = "SELECT userName FROM users WHERE userName LIKE ?";
    role="\"%" + role + "%\"";

    List<String> names = jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT userName FROM users where userName like ?", new RowMapper() {
          public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
            return resultSet.getString(1);
          }
        },role);
    System.out.println(names);
    return names;
}
```

I am not understanding why I am get this error , please can one say where it went wrong

```
Error message:
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT userName FROM users userName like ?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like '%blabla%'' at line 1
```

Comment: i am not understanding why ia am getting that error

Comment: your query dont have `like '%blabla%'`, is above pasted code is right?

Comment: oh sorry i pasted a wrong part of my code i will edit it

Comment: I have edited my question please refer it once again

Comment: Could it be that you are putting extra " in the role variable? Just use: `role="%" + role + "%";`

Comment: @Gunslinger it gave me similar error

Comment: What type is username in the database?

Comment: userName type is varchar in my database @Gunslinger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget the **`WHERE`** keyword in the `JdbcTemplate` query.